# How to evaluate $\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \frac{2}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2}dydx$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Problem: Evaluate the integral

$$\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \frac{2}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2}dydx$$

I am having a hard times understanding this concept and I couldn't solve this question. I was stuck at changing the cartesian to polar. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Welcome to Math stack exchange. Can you please put in your attempt at solving the solution. Your description of what you tried is unclear.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. This isn't an "unusual" Cartesian-to-polar problem. More generally$$\int_{-a}^a\int_{-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}^\sqrt{a^2-x^2} f(x,\,y)dydx=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^arf(r\cos\theta,\,r\sin\theta)drd\theta$$for $a>0$.

Comment: Hint: draw the region of integration.

Answer (score 0):

Recall polar coordinates are defined as $(x, y) \mapsto (r \cos(\phi), r \sin(\phi))$. It is an easy exercise to show that the determinant of the Jacobian reads $r(\cos(\phi)^2+\sin(\phi)^2)$.

Let us denote the integral by $I$. Substitute according to the rule given above and obtain
$I = \int_{r=0}^{1} \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} \frac{2}{\left(1+r^2\right)^2} r d\phi dr$.

I'll leave it as a tiny exercise for your to derive the boundaries of the intergral. In case you're not sure how to obtain them, a sketch might help!

Now we see, that we can directly carry out the integral over $\phi$ and obtain
$I = \int_{r=0}^{1} \frac{4\pi}{\left(1+r^2\right)^2} r  dr$.

It remains to calculate the integral over $r$. A simple substitution $t:=1+r^2$ yields
$I = \int_{t=1}^{2} \frac{2\pi}{t^2} dt = \pi$, where I leave the intermediate steps (like correctly determining the boundaries I gave) as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you it was very explaining!